# how to see in phpmyadmin if a column is already indexed?

Tags: phpmyadmin

plain simply question, I don't understand yet how to see it.

how to see in phpmyadmin if a column is already indexed?

e.g. i am in the structure view
[image]

if i click on index this happens:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to go to the Structure tab for the table and expand the "Indexes" link (you can do what I did and make it expanded by default by putting `$cfg['InitialSlidersState'] = 'open';` in your `config.inc.php`.

[image: Location of the Indexes link]

The Indexes link is just under "Add __ column(s)..." and once you expand it, you can see the indexes you've got and what type they are.